# how java indentifies a end of line in txt files

Tags: java

How does a `BufferedReader` identify the end of a line in a text file?

Also, if i have this code:

```
BufferedReader buff= new BufferedReader(file);
String line;
line=buff.readLine();
line=buff.readLine();
```

Does `line` have the value of the second line?

Comment: [A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the file has two lines. It will keep reading line by line as your call `readLine` until there are no more lines. Then, it will return `null`.

It identifies a line as ending by looking for:

> any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage
>   return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>    - [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

This way it accounts for how nearly all operating systems mark a newline, LF, CR, or CRLF. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.

Answer (score 0):

Well the documentation reads pretty clearly about the way [readline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) is implemented.

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Still, to add to the details its actual implementation in the class file is as follows :

```
public String readLine() throws IOException {
    return readLine(false);
}
```

Of course, what for overloaded.

```
/*...
@param      ignoreLF  If true, the next '\n' will be skipped..
 */
String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
```

So the ones used by you wouldn't skip any `\n` for sure and hence the *nth* usage of `line=buff.readLine();` shall store the *nth* line in the `file`.

***Note*** - Incomplete definition of the method, leaving a bit of research work for the reader.